# After initializer change 'alias_method' undefined method 'current_user' for class 'ApplicationController'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I've got the following initializer:

**app/config/initializers/store_location.rb**

```
module StoreLocation

  def self.skip_store_location
    [
        Devise::SessionsController,
        Devise::RegistrationsController,
        Devise::PasswordsController
    ].each do |controller|
      controller.skip_before_filter :store_location
    end
  end

  self.skip_store_location
end
```

Relevant parts of my ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :convert_legacy_cookies
  before_filter :store_location

  alias_method :devise_current_user, :current_user

  def current_user
    # do something
  end

  private
  def store_location
    # store location
  end
```

Plus this in
**config/environments/development.rb**

```
Foo::Application.configure do
# normal rails stuff
config.to_prepare do
    StoreLocation.skip_store_location
  end
end
```

If I let RSpec/Rails run the self.skip_store_location I'm getting the following error:

```
/foo/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:7:in `alias_method': undefined method `current_user' for class `ApplicationController' (NameError)
```

If I remove the call, everything is back to normal (except the filter is run, as expected). I'm guessing that I mess up dependency loading somehow?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is that you use `alias_method` before the method is defined in `ApplicationController`. To fix the problem, move the line

```
alias_method :devise_current_user, :current_user
```

below

```
def current_user
  # do something
end
```

It's a bit misleading that the error appears when running `skip_store_location`. I assume that happens because `skip_store_location` loads several controllers, and one of them is a subclass of `ApplicationController`.

Comment: I tried you approach but got StackLevel to deep errors, now I use a `super` call in the `current_user` method and it works. The important thing was to identify the culprit tough. Thanks alot you are a genius!

Comment: Hi Tammo, i just encountered that Spork isn't finding my ApplicationHelper methods since I implemented the SkipLocations feature. Do you have any quick guesses where the error could be?

Comment: I am not using Spork, so I only have generic quick guesses: If you get a `NoMethodError`/`NameError`, the file containing your code is not loaded. If your methods do not get called, it may be caused by `alias_method`. An example: if you `alias_method :b, :a` and change `a` afterwards, calls to `b` will call the old version of `a`, not the new version.

Comment: Hi Tammo / PizzaPill, can you write the code snippet of exactly how you solved the problem? The super method doesn't seem to be working for me..

Comment: Hi Rajat, my solution has been about fixing the `NameError` exception, which resulted from trying to use `alias_method` on a method not yet defined. Which is the issue you are having in your code?